# Using functional setState in forms

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I have been learning react and on setState i get about functional setState, i wanted to implement this on the forms to see how it works ( *please don't give me counter example,i am seeing if it can be implemented in forms for usage only* ).
I am trying to do this because i saw similar approach in a github but he had included all the things inside the single object, so he is doing it easily. But my question is can i do the same but without including my form properties like username and password inside object. I am talking about this repo => [Form Container](https://github.com/blizzerand/react-forms/blob/master/src/containers/FormContainer.jsx). What do you people recommend? How may i can do ? Thanks !

My form code is like this:

**index.js**

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Form extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: "",
            age: "",
        };
    }

    handleInput = (e) => {
        let name = e.target.name;
        let value = e.target.value;
        this.setState({ [name]: value });
    } 

//The block where i am trying to implement the function setState
    handleInput = (e) => {
        let name = e.target.name;
        let value = e.target.value;
        this.setState( state => ({
            name:{state.name,[name]: value}
        }));
    } 


    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <label> Name:
                <input type="text" name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleInput} />
                </label>
                <br />
                <label> Age:
                <input type="text" name="age" value={this.state.age} onChange={this.handleInput} />
                </label>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
handleInput = ({ target }) => {
  const { name, value } = target;

  this.setState({ [name]: [value] });
}

//Can even boil down to one line of code
handleInput = ({ target }) => this.setState({ [target.name]: [target.value] })
```

You may try the code above. It's pretty concise and not sure how to elaborate on it. We can discuss about my approach in comment

**UPDATES:**

```
let value = e.target.value;
this.setState( prevState => ({ 
  newUser : { ...prevState.newUser, name: value }
}), () => console.log(this.state.newUser))
```

The above code was copied from the link you commented which in our case, should be implemented as below:

```
handleInput = ({ target }) => {
  const { name, value } = target;

  this.setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.As you are using the event but i am trying to implement concept of  **previous state** to update the current state like in the github repo https://github.com/blizzerand/react-forms/blob/master/src/containers/FormContainer.jsx  .... in this git repo he has included the **key:value** pairs like _name_, _age_,_gender_,_skills_ and _about_ within the **newUser** object. Now my question is can i implement functional setState like he has done ( i.e. implementing previous State feature ) without including those **key:value** pairs within the **newUser** object but just them.